# how to divide content of a single elastic search index into multiple files?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

suppose there is an index in elastic search, i want that as soon as I enter the data in that index, in 1 file 10 data is stored only, after that new file created and next 10 data stored in newly created file by automation, like this goes on. How can I achieve that ? i am storing data in 1 file but not getting an idea how to divide it after certain data.

Comment: Are you fetching data from elasticsearch and writing it to a file output using logstash? Why is this tagged with the kibana tag?

Comment: I was trying to solve using index management in kibana, i am new to elk stack, i don't know which tech will be required from ELK stack for solving this issue.that's why i tagged all three.

Comment: for testing i am using stdin for writing and file output for storing the data.

Comment: You can configure ILM for elasticsearch in kibaba, and [rollover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-rollover.html#ilm-automatic-rollover) can be based on document count. I do not run kibana so I cannot help with that. I will say that a document limit of 10 is extremely low and will result in a large number of indexes, which is expensive.

Comment: i  assumed  10 doc for example , i am going to put a limit for 10000 doc, thanks, i am going to try this approach.